# Saving and loading image paths by NSUserdefaults

Tags: swift, uiimage, nsuserdefaults, nsdocumentdirectory

My app allows the user to select a logo from their photo library and save it to their documents directory as follows:

```
 var fileName:String = "logo.png"

        var arrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString

        var pngFileName = arrayPaths.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

       UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage).writeToFile(pngFileName, atomically:true)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(fileName, forKey: "pngFileName")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

I want to then use the image within another viewcontroller but I can't figure out how to access the image from their user defaults and then use in the current viewcontroller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the file name stored in the user defaults, you can find the application documents directory in the usual way - combine the two and you have your url. With this, you can display the image.

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
       .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let fileName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
               .stringForKey("pngFileName") ?? defaultName
let imagePath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)!
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath )

// display the image
someImageView.image = image
```

Comment: When I run your code I get an error NSUserDefaults does not have a member named 'stringForKey' - this is strange because the documentation states that it does.

Comment: Just tested in Playground: works as expected. Make sure you use `standardUserDefaults()` after the class name. I corrected the post by adding the `()`.

Comment: You should really be conditionally unwrapping the results of getting the filename from NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @Abizern Fair enough - I added a conditional default name.

Comment: spent a few hours trying to get this to tie into my stored file name... used this and wahhlaahh thanks a bunch for this...